# getting "Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string" - when it is a string

Tags: posts, errors

I have the following code in my functions.php, which executes a script upon publish:

```
function save_new_post($post_ID)
{

    $site_root = '/home/forexmag/public_html/directory2';
    $post = get_post($post_ID);
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $breaking_news = false;

    $categories = get_the_category($post_ID);
    if (is_array($categories) && !empty($categories))
    {
        foreach ($categories as $cat_det)
        {
            //this is the id for the breaking (bad) news
            if (5668 == $cat_det->cat_ID)
            {
                $breaking_news = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $exec_code = "/usr/local/bin/php 
            $site_root 
            /crons/cron_notify.php '$title' $post_ID 2 " . intval($breaking_news);
    exec(
        $exec_code
    );

}
add_action('publish_page', 'save_new_post', 10, 1);
```

When I publish a new post I keep getting the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in /home/forexmag/public_html/wp-content/themes/forex_magnates/functions.php on line 712
```

This line is where I set the `$exec_code` var.
However, as you can see, and as I confirmed via var_dump, the $title variable **is** a string.

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is $post_ID is an WP_Post not an int.

Comment: Nope. I've confirmed that it is an int

Comment: I don't know why your output looks right, because, as vancoder pointed out, "draft_to_publish" definitely provides a post object and not an ID. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/passing-post_id-to-wp_mail-please-help?replies=6

Comment: my bad, I was testing with publish_page. Edited accordingly. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magenta is actually correct. $post_ID is a WP_Post object. Your exec code should effectively be using $post_ID->ID.

```
function save_new_post($post_ID)
{
    print_r($post_ID);
    die();
```

Returns

```
WP_Post Object ( [ID] => ...
```

Comment: He showed the output of $post_ID, I don't understand why you are so sure.

Comment: I'm so sure because I tested it, and I read the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)

Comment: I elaborated on my answer accordingly.

Comment: I see. He is using a set function as part of an existing action. He is definitely using $post_ID wrong in that case. Gotcha. I wasn't paying attention to that action at the bottom...

Comment: What I still don't understand is the claim:What's even weirder is that when I var_dump $exec_code and kill the script, I get a perfect string string(121) "/usr/local/bin/php /home/forexmag/public_html/directory2 /crons/cron_notify.php '2011 Free  Free Forex Report' 9934 2 0" where 9934 is presumably the post id. Since class WP_Post has no __toString method. How can this be?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are doing your var_dump? Anyway, I would check if 9934 actually is the ID.

Comment: I am not doing the var_dump - the claim was originally made by Matanya but he has edited out now so it probably was in error.

Comment: Roger that. Sorry - confused Matanya with Magenta for a moment.